# Cannot open spyder after updating

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I tried to update my Spyder with terminal by `conda update qt pyqt`
but I tried both ways, through this command and through `pip`. Do you know how to wipe off entire anaconda config and the app itself?

*Whenever I try to open spyder, this message keeps appearing

```
objc[9494]: Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (0x10c490270) and /anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.5.dylib (0x10f143a80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 186, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 90, in 
from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

Comment: I think you just need to remove `/anaconda3` to uninstall Anaconda. By the way, the first line of the error you posted above clearly shows that you corrupted your Anaconda installation by using pip and conda at the same time to install PyQt 5. Now you really need to reinstall it to fix this problem. And for next, **don't** use pip to install a package that you can install with conda, because this problem will appear again.

Comment: I'm a beginner in python, and that code just did not make any sense to me. I was trying to update my Spyder, and I wasn't sure of what I'm not supposed to do. Anyways, problem solved, and thanks!